# Coding style for lot of CRUD using react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building a dashboard app with a lot of CRUD using react redux, So for each of the collections in database I would have its own page.

The problem is for each of them I would make an action, reducer, and a constant file and each of them will have similar actions like **fetch, fetchSuccess, fetchError, insert, insertSuccess, insertError, remove, removeSuccess, removeError, clearInsertError, clearRemoveError.**
Is it the right way to do it? I feel it is not really efficient because I have to repeatedly write constant in different files

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to have one `collections` reducer, and create actions (eg. `GET_COLLECTION`) that take the collection name as an argument, and stores the collection under its name as a key. Your constants can then be reduced to a single file, which lists the collections as strings - subroutes for the url of the endpoint, perhaps.

As an example, imagine we have a collection of Cars objects and a collection of Tyres, available at `/api/cars/` and `/api/tyres/` respectively. You could define constants for these routes as `CARS = 'cars/'` and `TYRES = 'tyres/'`, and then when stored in state the full collections reducer may look something like:

```
const state = {
    collections: {
        CARS: [/*list of cars*/],
        TYRES: [/*list of tyres*/],
    }
}
```

We might want to fetch all cars: we could use something like `getCollection(CARS)`, and then we should expect the reducer to store the result under `state.collections[CARS]`.

**EDIT: regarding responses** -

When storing response state, rather than using arrays (or lists) to store each collection, you could instead use an object with two keys - `response` and `items` perhaps. The `response` object should be updated with the same action as is used to fetch the collection - it should be set to 'PENDING' when the request is sent, and then either 'SUCCESS' if you get a successful response or 'FAILED' if the request fails. If the request fails, this would also be the place to store errors.

Another common pattern is to keep reducer structure as I have shown above, and create a separate reducer for response state. Again, this would respond to the same actions as the collections reducer, and store the response state for each collection in an object, where you could keep information about the request and any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how about the error, loading, and other state of each collections as there might be different state depend on the collections?